# custom endpoint in woocommerce gateway with callback

Tags: wordpress, callback, woocommerce, gateway

I am building a gateway that works with a callback to tell us about the status of an order.

```
 <?php

    class WC_Gateway_Pay extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
       public function __construct() {
           // ...
           add_action( 'woocommerce_api_' . strtolower( get_class( $this ) ), array( &$this, 'check_pay_response' ) );
       }

       // ...

       public function check_pay_response() { // ... }
   }
```

Is there any way for the `check_pay_response` function to be run on the `mysite/wc-api/wc_gateway_pay/confirm` endpoint instead of `mysite/wc-api/wc_gateway_pay`?